# NullPointerException on initialized variable?

Tags: java, android, button, textview

I have a problem with TextView [?], I initialized textview because I want to make it scrollable but I've got an error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     dc = new DigitalClock(this);
     textViewMesssage = new TextView(this);
     dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
     textViewMesssage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
     textViewMesssage.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     addListenerOnButton();

}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    buttonTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                                  String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        }

    });
}
```

main.xml

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="MainActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"  
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_gravity="right"

    />
```

and error

> 20:36:04.407   18740   XXX.X   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   20:36:04.407    18740   XXX.X   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at XXX.X.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
>   40 line is `textViewMesssage.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

I'm using API lvl 8

Comment: Where is line 40 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice He told that, look closer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.main);` must be called before you try getting any views from the layout XML.

Answer (score 2):

Put :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

at the top of onCreate, also this code makes no sense:

```
 dc = new DigitalClock(this);
 textViewMesssage = new TextView(this);
 dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1); //<< overwrites dc, and is not present in layout
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new text view with

```
textViewMesssage = new TextView(this);
```

and then promptly throw it away with

```
textViewMesssage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
```

which can potentially return `null`. In this case it does because at this point in your code, you have not yet call `setContentView();`. Remember that you must call `setContentView();` before calling `findViewById()`. Because of this, I suggest writing `setContentView()` as the **second** line of every `onCreate()` method (after super.onCreate()`).

Answer (score 0):

why do you need these two lines, delete them check if it works

```
 dc = new DigitalClock(this);
 textViewMesssage = new TextView(this);
```

and add

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: This is a good observation, but doesn't solve the OP's NPE problems.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice edited my answer. hope this one works